# Conceito de um sistema de loja virtual SaaS

Tags: php, saas

Boa noite, desenvolvi um sistema que se comporta no formado SaaS, onde o cliente apenas se cadastrar e já tem acesso para utilização, nele usei um identificador único para cada cliente e todos eles usam a mesma estrutura, arquivos PHP e o Mesmo banco de dados. Até aí tudo bem, pois o dominio não muda, ou seja, todo mundo usa o www.lalalaetc.com.br/app e o sistema separa tudo pelo identificador único, porém, gostaria de desenvolver uma loja virtual a partir dele, só que aí teria uma diferença, o dominio, ou seja, acredito que o principio seja o mesmo, usar um identificador unico para cada loja, mas minha duvida é como que farei para que quando alguem acessar a loja o dominio seja direcionado corretamente e carregue o id do meu cliente? Qual o caminho a seguir e sobre o que preciso pesquisar para fazer tal façanha?

Comment: *cliquei reabrir sem querer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a variável `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` irá obter o domínio que foi acessado. Sendo assim, com essa informação você poderá obter a empresa desejada.

Ai vem a forma como sua aplicação foi desenvolvida. Caso você trate a empresa atual em todas as áreas do sistema e não possui padrões que permitam que você execute um código antes da inicialização do aplicativo (como o [FrontController](https://www.devmedia.com.br/padroes-de-projetos-introducao-aos-padroes-front-controller-e-command/30644), você poderá criar uma classe que possa utilizar sempre que desejar verificar o domínio, caso possua, a basta colocar neste local que tudo irá funcionar tranquilamente.